# Why the second parameter of strchr() is an integer?

Tags: c, memory, parameters, language-lawyer, standard-library

I would to know why the second parameter of the standard function *strchr* is an integer knowing that it will be casted to a char ?

The prototype :

```
strchr(const char *s, int c)
```

Comment: `int c` is means the character that you want to search. The character is passed as an integer, but in fact only the lower 8 bits are searched. It should therefore be handed over to a char

Comment: So it is the same as tolower(), isspace(), memset(), memchr(), strrchr(), putchar(), etc.  Consistency is important :)

Comment: It's for consistency with versions of `strchr` in old K&R versions of C which had no prototypes and arguments narrower than an `int` would be promoted to `int`.